# Autodesk Viewer - resources caching on the client

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using autodesk viewer api https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/overview/

We are using Angular/Ionic2 to show the the model in our tablets.

What I observed is the veiwer resources are not cached on the client
eg resources:

- objects_attrs.json.gz
- objects_vals.json.gz
- 0.pf
- 1.pf,
- etc.,

How can I cache these resources on the client?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bubble extraction example (https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io), and its' live demo is https://extract.autodesk.io. This might help you to download the derivative files from the Forge service, then use the viewer under the offline mode.

And you might be interested in this blog article **[Viewer on airplane mode](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-airplane-mode)**. It demonstrated some basic scenario for caching derivative files.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  But my question more about online mode and caching the resources on the client.

Comment: Hi, Apologizing for the late response. Could you share with us how the Angular/Ionic2 cache other resource?

Comment: In addition, we are interested in your need for caching derivative files. After checking with our dev team, those files will be cached by the browser for 24 hours via the `mag-age` of the`cache-control`. Didn't this not match your need?